# serverspec command returning blank strings

Tags: ruby, rspec, docker

I am trying to test a Dockerfile using rspec, serverspec and docker-api gems. For the most part my tests are passing but all the tests that are using the `command` method are failing and returning blank strings regardless of the commands I am supplying.

The code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/tomasbasham/nginx) but the most salient files are below:

My Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile for nginx with configurable persistent volumes

# Select nginx as the base image
FROM nginx

# Mount configurable persistent volumes
VOLUME ["/etc/nginx/sites-enabled", "/etc/nginx/certs", "/etc/nginx/conf.d", "/var/log/nginx", "/var/www/html"]

# Expose both HTTP and HTTPS ports
EXPOSE 80 443

# ENTRYPOINT
ENTRYPOINT ["service", "nginx", "start"]
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

group :development, :test do
  gem 'specinfra',  '~> 2.12.7'
  gem 'serverspec', '~> 2.8.2'
  gem 'docker-api', '~> 1.21.4'
  gem 'rspec',      '~> 3.2.0'
end
```

spec:

```
require 'serverspec'
require 'docker'

Excon.defaults[:ssl_verify_peer] = false

describe 'Dockerfile' do
  before(:all) do
    image =  Docker::Image.build_from_dir('.')

    set :os, family: :debian
    set :backend, :docker
    set :docker_image, image.id
  end

  it 'installs the right version of Debian' do
    expect(os_version).to include('Debian GNU/Linux 7')
  end

  describe package('nginx') do
    it { should be_installed }
  end

  describe service('nginx') do
    it { should be_enabled }
    it { should be_running }
  end

  describe command('nginx -V') do
    its(:stdout) { should include('http_ssl_module') }
    its(:stdout) { should include('http_gzip_static_module') }
  end

  describe port(80) do
    it { should be_listening }
  end

  describe port(443) do
    it { should be_listening }
  end

  def os_version
    command('lsb_release -a').stdout
  end
end
```

I am aware I am using old versions of the gems but I was unable to get this working at all with the latest versions. If it is of any relevance I am on OS X and therefore using boot2docker. The results I am getting from running my spec is:

```
Failures:

  1) Dockerfile installs the right version of Debian
     Failure/Error: expect(os_version).to include('Debian GNU/Linux 7')
       expected "" to include "Debian GNU/Linux 7"

     # ./spec/dockerfile_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Dockerfile Command "nginx -V" stdout should include "http_ssl_module"
     Failure/Error: its(:stdout) { should include('http_ssl_module') }
       expected "" to include "http_ssl_module"

     # ./spec/dockerfile_spec.rb:29:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Dockerfile Command "nginx -V" stdout should include "http_gzip_static_module"
     Failure/Error: its(:stdout) { should include('http_gzip_static_module') }
       expected "" to include "http_gzip_static_module"

     # ./spec/dockerfile_spec.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across something similar when upstream specinfra gems were changed (Specinfra [2.37.0](https://github.com/mizzy/specinfra/releases/tag/v2.37.0) and [2.37.1](https://github.com/mizzy/specinfra/releases/tag/v2.37.0)) with the handling of stderr and stdout.  Try running the command manually with redirects to see where the output is coming from:

```
nginx -V 2>/dev/null
```

If you end up with no output then it's spitting out into stderr.  A workaround would be to use 2>&1 on the end to drop everything into stdout.

** update in response to comment

```
~$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.4.4
built by gcc 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
TLS SNI support enabled
<snip>
~$ nginx -V 2>/dev/null
~$
```

Comment: I assume when you say run the command manually, you mean in irb?

Comment: updated answer as needed better formatting than comment offered

Comment: Running through the command line outputs things as expected (nothing is getting directed to stderr). If it helps I have created a github repo for this project. I'll update the question with this link

Comment: I went back to this and updated my gems. I am also now building my Dockerfile manually instead of relying on the docker-api gem and you were right. `nginx -V` was printing to `stderr`. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I'd say it's just the way that nginx is written.  It could be so that in case of an option error the error and usage information are caught in `stderr` which would be caught and logged out?  More of a question for Nginx themselves :)